# How to parse XML using php with html tag inside XML tags?

Tags: php, html, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<activities>

<activity category="Team">
<date><h4>Date: January 15, 2017</h4></date>
 <work> 
    <li><b>MR X</b> working on X</li>
    <li><b>MR Y</b> working on Y</li></li>
    <li><b>MR Z</b> working on Z</li></li>
 </work>
 </activity>

 </activities>
```

The above one is the XML file. Suppose the file name is activities.xml.

Now below is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$xmls=simplexml_load_file("activities.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xmls as $xml) {
  echo $xml->date;
  echo $xml->work;
}
?>
```

I want to get the date and work details with `<h4>` tag and `<li>` tag and others so that I can work with them in HTML directly.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two extra `</li>` which causes a parse error, except that everythinhg seems good for what you want to do with. Here is the object I obtain :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [activity] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Team
                )

            [date] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [h4] => Date: January 15, 2017
                )

            [work] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [li] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [b] => MR X
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [b] => MR Y
                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [b] => MR Z
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It help me to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file_exists('activities.xml')) {
    try{
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('activities.xml') or die('Can not load');

        $date = $xml->{activity}->{date}->{h4};
        echo $date.'<br/>';
        foreach($xml->{activity}->{work}->{li} as $work){
             echo $work->{b};
             echo $work.'<br/>';
        }

    }catch (\Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

And proper activities.xml file content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<activities>
    <activity category="Team">
        <date><h4>Date: January 15, 2017</h4></date>
        <work>
            <li><b>MR X</b> working on X</li>
            <li><b>MR Y</b> working on Y</li>
            <li><b>MR Z</b> working on Z</li>
        </work>
    </activity>
</activities>
```

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. 

But if I want to get the inside tag directly. For example if I want to ge the data with <li> and <b> tag is that possible?

Comment: As far as i think it is not possible with the current logic (simplexml_load_file). Maybe that can achieve using the file handling.